# Spring JPA: Error saving object with composite key containing foreign key

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, composite-key

I am trying to map **existing database tables** using Spring JPA (Hibernate).  For example, one table (THING) has a composite primary key containing a foreign key to another table (PLACE).  I have attempted to map this by creating a separate IdClass for Thing but am getting `Can not set cktest.Place field cktest.ThingId.place to java.lang.Long` when I try to `save` a `Thing` via `CrudRepository<Thing, ThingId>`

Is my mapping incorrect, or is this a JPA limitation?  Is there a work-around?

Place.java:

```
@Entity
public class Place {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name = "ID")
  private long id;

  @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false)
  private String name;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "place")
  Set<Thing> things;

  ... constructor, get/set methods, equals, hashCode ...
}
```

Thing.java:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(ThingId.class)
public class Thing {
  @Id
  String name;

  @Id
  Place place;

  ... constructors, get/set methods, equals, hashCode ...
}
```

ThingId.java:

```
@Embeddable
public class ThingId implements Serializable {
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "PLACE_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", nullable = false)
  private Place place;

  @Column(name="NAME")
  private String name;
}
```

ThingRepository.java:

```
... imports ...
public interface ThingRepository extends CrudRepository<Thing, ThingId> {}
```

Main.java:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Main.class);
    PlaceRepository placeRepository = context.getBean(PlaceRepository.class);
    ThingRepository thingRepository = context.getBean(ThingRepository.class);

    // save a place
    Place home = placeRepository.save(new Place("Home"));

    // save a thing
    Thing re = new Thing(home, "Fido");
    // Throws 

    thingRepository.save(re);  

    context.close();
  }
}
```